# asp:button onclick doesn't fire and page only refreshes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

Here's my aspx code for my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

And here's the function for the onclick event in a codebehind file:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblOutput.Text = txtFirstName.Text;
}
```

Alternatively, I've also used this in the onclick function, to see if the problem was the problem was the script in the function and not the button itself:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Unfortunately this didn't work either. So the problem is probably something going wrong when the button is clicked, right?

The code behind is properly linked, because other functions in the page_load are working fine.

All that happens when my button is clicked is the page refreshes. To be honest I'm not sure if I could call it a refresh, the values in the from are still there, the page just jumps back to the top and nothing else happens.

I've also tried creating a second button, with a slightly different ID and onclick name, but the page still acts the same. I'm at a complete loss here. I haven't found anything on google that helps.

**EDIT:** Here's the full asp file. We're using ektron as a CMS so there's some weird code for that as well. And before anybody asks, yes it's in a form tag.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/InteriorPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="urmintakeform.cs" Inherits="urmintakeform" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Ektron.Cms.Controls" Namespace="Ektron.Cms.Controls" TagPrefix="CMS" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageBody" Runat="Server">

    <div id="two-column-pagenav" class="section-divider-small">
        <div class="column-one"><h2>University Relations and Marketing</h2></div>
            <div class="column-two">
                <p class="breadcrumb">
                    <CMS:FolderBreadcrumb ID="FolderBreadcrumb1" runat="server" DynamicParameter="id" SuppressWrapperTags="true" SuppressAddEdit="true" />
                </p>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img alt="URM Banner" src="/images/department_banners/urm-banner.jpg" />
        <asp:Literal ID="litDeptImage" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="" class="container section-divider-small">
        <div class="column-one">
            <div class="nav-aside widget">
                <div class="opener-block">
                    <a href="#" class="opener"><span>Menu</span></a>
                    <span class="title">University Relations and Marketing</span>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-page-box nav-slide">
                    <!--Replace this code with the Ektron Flex Menu Control-->
                    <CMS:FlexMenu ID="FlexMenu1" runat="server" SuppressAddEdit="true" DefaultMenuID="15032386736" DisplayXslt="xml/departments.xsl" SuppressWrapperTags="true" CacheInterval="0"  AllowClose="true" EnableSmartOpen="True" AutoCollapseBranches="True" StartCollapsed="True" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-holder">
                <div class="dept-contact-box widget">
                    <h4>How to Reach Us</h4>
                    <p><span style="font-weight: bold">University Relations and Marketing</span><br />
                        xxxx<br />
                        xxxx<br />
                        xxxxx<br />
                        xxxx<a href="tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a><br />
                        Email: <a href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a><br />
                    </p>
                    <div class="dept-social-media">
                        <a title="Twitter" href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" target="_blank">
                            <img src="/images/socmed_icons/twitter-32x432.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body-content" class="column-two">
            <div class="content-body">
                <div id="ctl00_PageBody_ContentBlock1" class="content-container">
                    <div class="content-holder">
                        <asp:Literal ID="litInPageTopNav" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrContent" runat="server" />
                        <CMS:FormBlock ID="FormBlock1" runat="server" DynamicParameter="ekfrm" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="intake">

                    <h2>Tell us about yourself</h2>
                    <div class="userinfo">
                        <label id="firstname" runat="server" text="First Name:" >First Name:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" placeholder="First Name"></asp:TextBox><p></p>

                        <label id="lblLastName" runat="server" text="">Last Name:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" placeholder="Last Name"></asp:TextBox><p></p>

                        <label id="lblDepartment" runat="server" text="">Department:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDepartment" runat="server" MaxLength="50" placeholder="Department"></asp:TextBox><p></p>
                    </div>
                    <!--  Phone and Email  --------->
                    <div class="job">
                        <label id="lblPhone" runat="server" text="">Phone:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="50" placeholder="Phone"></asp:TextBox><p></p>

                        <label id="lblEmail" runat="server" text="Email">Email:</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="50" placeholder="Email"></asp:TextBox><p></p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <div class="help">
                        <h2>How can we help you?</h2>

                        <label id="lblCategory" runat="server" text="Help">Get Help With: </label>

                        <select name="areaselector" id="areaselector">
                            <option value="select">Select an Option</option>
                            <option value="design">Design</option>
                            <option value="imprinted">Imprinted</option>
                            <option value="photography">Photography</option>
                            <option value="social">Social Media</option>
                            <option value="written">Written Content</option>
                        </select>

                        <div id="design" class="areas" style="display:none" onchange="">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="designASP" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="appendToSelectedList">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="brochures">Brochures</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="posters">Posters</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="postcards">Postcards</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="booklets">Booklets</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="advertisement">Advertisement Design</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="digitalMarketing">Digital Marketing Material</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="other">Other Promotional Material</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </div>

                        <div id="imprinted" class="areas" style="display:none">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="imprintedASP" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="appendToSelectedList">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="licensed vendors">Licensed Vendors</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Imprinted product search/sample products">Imprinted product search/sample products</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="billboard leasing">Billboard Leasing</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Imprinted product art/design">Imprinted product art/design</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="table covers">Table covers</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="retractable banners">Retractable banners</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="temporary signage">Temporary signage</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="tigerizing">"Tigerizing"</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </div>

                        <div id="photography" class="areas" style="display:none">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="photographyASP" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="appendToSelectedList">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Official faculty and staff portraits">Official facutly and staff portraits</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Groups and/or organizatoin portraits">Groups and/or organization Portraits</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Organization Event photos">Organization Event photos</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Student Event photos">Student Event photos</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Departmental brochure and web photos">Departmental brochure and web photos</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Sporting events">Sporting events</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Guest speakers">Guest speakers</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="ID and/or nametags">ID and/or nametags</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Visa\passports photographs">Visa\passports photographs</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Scanning, retouching and custom printing">Scanning, retouching and custom printing</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Archive/history FHSU image retrieval">Archive/history FHSU image retrieval</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </div>

                        <div id="social" class="areas" style="display:none">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="socialASP" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="appendToSelectedList">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Training">Training</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Event coverage">Event coverage</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Marketing/promotion">Marketing/Promotion</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </div>

                        <div id="written" class="areas" style="display:none">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="writtenASP" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="appendToSelectedList">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Print">Print</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Web">Web</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tellusmore">
                        <h2>Tell us more about your request</h2>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tellUsMoreBox" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Columns="50" Rows="6" />
                    </div>

                    <!--<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit Application" Enabled="true" CssClass="submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                    <asp:Button ID="asdf" runat="server" Text="Submit Application" Enabled="true" CssClass="submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />-->


                    <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" CausesValidation="false"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here's the C# file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ContentBlock ContentBlock1 = new ContentBlock();
        ContentBlock1.SuppressWrapperTags = true;
        ContentBlock1.DefaultContentID = 64;
        ContentBlock1.DynamicParameter = "id";
        ContentBlock1.Page = this.Page;
        ContentBlock1.Fill();
        //this.ltrContent.Text = ContentBlock1.Text.Replace("width", "max-width");
        string lsContent = ContentBlock1.Text.Replace("width:", "max-width:");
        lsContent = lsContent.Replace("width=", "max-width=");
        //this.ltrContent.Text = lsContent;
        //this.ContentBlock1.Text = lsContent;

        FolderBreadcrumb1.Text += " > <a href=\"" + ContentBlock1.EkItem.QuickLink + "\" class=\"active-link\">" + new CultureInfo("en").TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Server.HtmlDecode(ContentBlock1.EkItem.Title)) + "</a>";

        // dynamically generate an image if it been added as a meta image selector
        Ektron.Cms.CustomAttributeList ContentMetaData;
        ContentMetaData = ContentBlock1.GetMetaData();

        if (ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("department-image").Value.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            string extension;
            extension = Path.GetExtension(Convert.ToString(ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("department-image").Value));
            string ext = extension.Substring(0, 4);
            if (ext == ".swf")
            {
                //is flash
                litDeptImage.Text = "<object id=\"myId\" classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\" width=\"730\" height=\"175\">";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  <param name=\"movie\" value=\"" + Convert.ToString(ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("department-image").Value) + "\" />";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  <!--[if !IE]>-->";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  <object type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" data=\"" + Convert.ToString(ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("department-image").Value) + "\" width=\"730\" height=\"175\">";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  <!--<![endif]-->";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  <div>";
                litDeptImage.Text += "      <p>You have javascript turned off or are not running the latest version of Adobe Flash Player. To best view this site, please <a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer\"><img src=\"http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif\" alt=\"Get Adobe Flash player\" /></a></p>";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  </div>";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  <!--[if !IE]>-->";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  </object>";
                litDeptImage.Text += "  <!--<![endif]-->";
                this.litDeptImage.Text += "</object>";
            }
            else
            {
                //else image
                litDeptImage.Text = "<img class=\"ImageInline\" src=\"" + Convert.ToString(ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("department-image").Value) + "\" alt=\" \" />";
            }
        }
        //grab collection id from the folder id that the content block belongs to
        Ektron.Cms.API.Content.Content apiContent = new Ektron.Cms.API.Content.Content();
        Ektron.Cms.Content.EkContent ekContent = apiContent.EkContentRef;
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection colldat = ekContent.GetAllCollectionsInfo(ContentBlock1.EkItem.FolderId, "id");
        string collid = null;
        foreach (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection field in colldat)
        {
            collid = field[1].ToString(); // collection id
        }

        long collint = Convert.ToInt64(collid);
        //create the collection object we'll be using to get department nav pages
        Ektron.Cms.Controls.Collection coll = new Collection();
        coll.DefaultCollectionID = collint;
        // set the standard coll properties
        coll.DisplayXslt = "xml/departments-nav.xsl";
        // attatch it to our invisible literal and fill it
        coll.Page = Page;
        coll.Fill();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(collid))
            litInPageTopNav.Text = coll.Text;

        //Use the meta data we grabbed earlier to display title, keywords and description
        Literal1.Text = "<title>" + Convert.ToString(ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("Title").Value) + " - xxxxxx University</title>\n";
        Literal1.Text += "<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"" + Convert.ToString(ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("Keywords").Value) + "\">\n";
        Literal1.Text += "<meta name=\"description\" content=\"" + Convert.ToString(ContentMetaData.GetItemByName("Description").Value) + "\">\n";

        //lblOutput.Text = Output;


    }
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblOutput.Text = txtFirstName.Text;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** Here's the  tag that's on the page when viewing the pages source at run-time, provided by I believe possibly the master file. As I said earlier we use ektron cms. Could the form tag be a problem?

```
<form method="post" action="/urm/intake/" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="if(&#39;undefined&#39; == typeof Ektron || !Ektron.FormBlock || !typeof Ektron.FormBlock.validate  || Ektron.FormBlock.validate(this)){$ektron(&#39;input[type=submit]&#39;).attr(&#39;disabled&#39;,&#39;disable&#39;);return true;}else{return false;}">
```

Comment: in your `page_load` handler write this and see `Button1.Click += new eventhandler(Button1_Click)`

Comment: post your aspx and .cs code as well

Comment: "The type or namespace name "eventhandler" could not be found." And I'll update OP with the full code in a second.

Comment: Is your button inside a `<form>` tag?

Comment: Also, make sure you are not using any sort of `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Yes to the form tag and I'm not sure about the UpdatePanel. On the top of my head i'm not using one. OP is updated.

Comment: If you remove the `Button1_Click` event handler from the C# code file, do you see an error when the form is displayed at runtime?

Comment: Place that button outside `<asp:Content ID="Content4"` and see if it hits the event handler. If yes then check with your master page aspx

Comment: @ConnorsFan: Yes there is an error at runtime.

Comment: your codeFile is set to "urmintakeform.cs".  Isn't that yourAspPageFile.aspx.cs ?  also can you check your class definition ?

Comment: @Rahul putting it outside the content tag caused an error at runtime. Do you mean putting the button in the master file? If so, would I move the handler into the master's code file too, or no?

Comment: @g2000 Does it make a difference if the code behind is a different name as the aspx file? My aspx file is titled, "department-URMintake-form.aspx", and the code behind is as you said, "urmintakeform.cs". The class definition is `public partial class urmintakeform : System.Web.UI.Page {...}` and everything before the page_load function is just initializing variables.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The CMS was the one at fault. I was viewing the page online with the URL given by the Ektron CMS. changing the formblock

```
<CMS:FormBlock ID="FormBlock1" runat="server" DynamicParameter="ekfrm" />
```

to a content block fixed it. The form block in ektron CMS caused problems.